# Is $X^{\mu\nu} \equiv A^{\mu}+B^{\nu}$ a tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus

Consider $X^{\mu \nu}$ an "object" with two indices, defined as $X^{\mu\nu} = A^{\mu}+B^{\nu}$. Is $X^{\mu\nu}$ a tensor? Exists some transformation law to carry $X$ to a new coordinate system ?

What I need to prove? I have that, if $X^{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor, $$X^{\alpha\beta} = \Lambda^{\alpha}_{\mu}\Lambda_{\mu}^{\beta}X^{\mu\nu} $$

Where $A^{\alpha} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}$ and $B^{\beta} = \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta}B^{\nu}$. And then I have that 
$$X^{\alpha\beta} = \Lambda_{\mu}^{\alpha}A^{\mu} +  \Lambda_{\nu}^{\beta}B^{\nu}$$

I don't really understand this steps, my teacher assistant did this, but I can't see how he has separated the tensor, and why $X^{\alpha\beta}$ has that structure. Any hint o explanation will be really appreciate it :)

Comment: It is not a tensor.

Comment: @0celo7 Yes, if I have two 1-form $\tilde{p}$ and $\tilde{q}$, a 2-form is $\tilde{p}\otimes\tilde{q}$. But, how can I do an explicit demonstration? (: I think that if I have this two 1-form, and I do $X(\tilde{p},\tilde{q}) \Rightarrow X^{\alpha\beta}N_{\alpha}M_{\beta}  = (A\cdot N)M_{\beta}+(B\cdot M)N_{\alpha}$ and that it's not a scalar, or not?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for math.stackexchange?

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about forms...but a 2-form is the antisymmetrized tensor product of two 1-forms.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan yes, maybe. I see this on my course of General Relativity, so it's a mathematical question, but physicists knows better how to work with this notation.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Is it typeset correctly? Why would the sum of two vectors make a tensor?

Comment: @SebastiánMolina You can show that the product with a form is not linear with respect to the forms. Another way is obviously to take the two transformation equations from your post and simply show that they are not equal (i.e. the vector-sum does not transform as a tensor), this is probably what the instructor expects.

Comment: Of course the components $X^{\mu\nu} = A^\mu + B^\nu$ form a tensor. It's just not the same tensor as that with components $X^{\alpha\beta} = A^\alpha + B^\beta$, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are understood to be in one coordinate system, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in another. See my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206739/how-to-prove-a-symmetric-tensor-is-indeed-a-tensor/206890#206890).

Comment: @ChrisWhite Well and in physics we define tensors as being invariant under coordinate transformation, so $A^\mu + B^\nu$ is *not* a tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tensor is something that transforms like a tensor.

The sum of two vectors transforms as
$$
(A^\alpha + B^\beta)^\prime = \Lambda^\alpha_\mu A^\mu + \Lambda^\beta_\nu B^\nu
$$
A tensor transforms as
$$
(T^{\alpha\beta})^\prime = \Lambda^\alpha_\mu \Lambda^\beta_\nu T^{\mu\nu}
$$
If $A^\alpha + B^\beta$ doesn't transform like a tensor, it isn't a tensor.

Answer (score 3):

The expression $A^{\mu}+B^{\nu}$ is not a tensor. It is not even an allowed operation, since tensors only add to tensors with the same index structure (and same index "names").

To see that $X^{\mu\nu}=A^{\mu}+B^{\nu}$ is not consistent mathematically, perform a contraction of both sides with the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. On the left hand side you get a scalar (a number), since both indices were contracted. On the right hand side you get $A_{\nu}+B_{\mu}$, which is certainly not a number.

(I hope that at this point of your studies you are familiar with contracting with the metric tensor. If not, think of the contraction as a linear operation that turns a column vector (upper index) to a row vector (lower index), and a matrix (two upper indices) to a number).